# Pair проблема с выводом

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Вот в такой простенькой программе ошибка 1 неразрешенных внешних элементов

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    pair <int,char> p1(1,'a'),p2(p1);
    p2=make_pair<int,char>(2,'b');
    cout<<"p1:"<<p1.first<<" "<<p1.second<<endl;
    cout<<"p2:"<<p2.first<<" "<<p2.second<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: заменил void на int и system("PAUSE"); на return 0; и все скомпилировалось.

Comment: да тоже изменил но та же ошибка

Comment: тогда скопируйте текст ошибки и покажите ее.

Answer (score 0):

У функции `main` есть 2 стандартных типа, ни один из которых не подходит под ваше определение. Поэтому надо заменить `void` на `int`. Во-вторых, для `std::system` нужен хедер `<cstdlib>`, а у вас его нет.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    pair <int,char> p1(1,'a'),p2(p1);
    p2=make_pair<int,char>(2,'b');
    cout<<"p1:"<<p1.first<<" "<<p1.second<<endl;
    cout<<"p2:"<<p2.first<<" "<<p2.second<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

В таком виде ошибок нет https://godbolt.org/z/99d5WG